# Looping with condition. Do until numbers end

Tags: excel, vba

I have a cell with a full address. I want to copy street name and street number to the next cell. E.g "STRANDVEJEN 100 MIDDELFART DENMARK"

In this example I want "STRANDVEJEN 100" to be copied.

Currently everything is being copied to the next cell.
But I need advice how to continue

```
Sub move()
    Range("C3:C2000").Copy Range("D3:D2000")
    Do until......
End Sub
```

I need help with the do until part.

Comment: I guess you are taking `D3:D2000` because your data won't exceed that but you want to stop on the last row with data which could be `D958`. Is that it?

Comment: The list of addresses is from C3:C2000:
NORDVEJ 3 SLAGELSE DENMARK,
NORDGÅRDE 1A SVINNINGE DENMARK,
DRAGSTRUPVEJ 42;DRAGSTRUP CEMENTSTØBERI APS ERSLEV 
DENMARK,
NORDGÅRDE 1A SVINNINGE DENMARK,

So I just want to copy street name + street number to the next cells D2:D2000

Comment: Then where do your numbers end?

Comment: You are gonna need to split your adresses and use most likely regex to handle this.

Comment: I have one address in each cell going from C2:C2000. So number ends in every cell

Comment: You show `NORDGÅRDE 1A SVINNINGE DENMARK` as one of your addresses. Do you really want to split this after the `1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyYes()

    Dim arr As Variant, strSplit As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        arr = .Range("C3:C2000")

        For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)

            strSplit = Split(arr(i, 1), " ")

            .Range("E" & i + 2).Value = strSplit(0)

            .Range("F" & i + 2).Value = strSplit(1)

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

**Results:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that will perform your 'cut' on a string. It's not pretty and it could no doubt be better written with a simple reg-ex command but..

```
Function untilnumeric(txt As String) As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim started As Boolean
    For i = 1 To Len(txt)
        If Asc(Mid(txt, i, 1)) > 47 And Asc(Mid(txt, i, 1)) < 58 Then
            started = True
        Else
            If started = True And Asc(Mid(txt, i, 1)) = 32 Then
                untilnumeric = Left(txt, i - 1)
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

You could use it like this to perform it on column C - copying the result to D:

```
Range("D3:D2000").Value = Range("C3:C2000").Value
For Each c In Range("D3:D2000").Cells
    c.Value = untilnumeric(c.Value)
Next
```

Note: Amended slightly to pick up any letters within the number part. eg.100A